# OpenFileDialog VB.net 2010

Tags: .net, vb.net, controls, openfiledialog

is there anyway where instead of grabbing the url of this control in this way "C:/Users/etc/etc/file.txt" and grab it in "~/temp/file.txt".

If so, could you help me with it? I've been working so hard trying to find a way on google and I haven't found anything that could help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you explain better what you are trying to do? Grab what? An example of what is not working would be helpful.

Comment: I mean, i want to grab the direction of an specific file, but it gets it in this way:

    C:/User/etc/etc/file.txt

I don't need it in that way, I need it in this way 

    ~/etc/etc/file.txt

Comment: And actually it's working with the full path (C:/etc/etc/etc/file.txt) but I need it in the way I said (~/etc/etc/file.txt)

Comment: This is some kind of bizarre mix of Windows and Unix names.  The ~ character doesn't mean anything special in Windows nor does it have an equivalent.

Comment: Perhaps something to do with the root path of a [website](http://forums.asp.net/t/1192033.aspx/1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenFileDialog property FileName returns the full path of the selected file (as from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename.aspx))

To get only part of this fullpath you can use the methods of the [Path class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx).
For example (assuming selectedPath as the return from OpenFileDialog.FileName):

```
Dim selectedPath As string = "C:\Users\etc\etc\file.txt"
Dim dirPart as String() = selectedPath.Split("\")
Dim idx As Integer = dirPart.Length
Dim lastPart = Path.Combine("~", dirPart(idx-3), dirPart(idx-2), dirPart(idx-1))
Console.WriteLine(lastPart)
```

Of course you should be sure that you get at least 3 parts from your selectedpath

Answer (score 0):

Dim selectedPath As string = "C:\Users\etc\etc\file.txt"
Dim dirPart as String() = selectedPath.Split("\")

Return dirPart(UBound(dirPart))